# Refresh primefaces datagrid frequently (alternative way to Poll)

Tags: jsf-2, datagrid, primefaces

I need to refresh my *PrimeFaces* datagrid (version 3.3.1) every 30 seconds to fetch the modified value from database. Currently I'm using *PrimeFaces* poll, but it causing performance issue as every time makes a call to a database.

Is there any other way to refresh the content?

```
 <p:poll interval="30" listener="#{BoardAction.Search}" update="boardpanel"/>
```

search is the function being called during the refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is some other trigger that you can rely on to initiate the refresh you should use [Push (by primefaces - since 3.4 version)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf)

You you'll use push the refresh will occur only when needed and not every 30 seconds, so you can save call to db

If you must do the refresh every 30 seconds , poll is the thing you need to use (You might consider fine tuning in you back-end code , maybe you db call could be improved)

Comment: That's the third time I see someone saying push has been introduced in 3.4. Maybe I'm mad but I have seen it before. [This blog post](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2053) announced push in July 2012.

Comment: @siebz0r It was available before the 3.4 (but it had lots of issues and wasn't something that you'd like to use in production INMO), so the stable and reliable version it was **Unleashed** in 3.4. About the blog post , it also says *PrimeFaces Push will be available in upcoming 3.4 release which is due early August.*

Comment: Ah, thanks ;-) missed the part about the stable version being released in 3.4.